# What control should I use for implementing my own ajax-enabled auto complete box?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css, ajax

I've been trying to add auto complete functionality to a text box. I want to make an Ajax call to a database with the text box content as well as the selected search field(chosen from a separate drop-down) as parameters. I was able to get it working with the AjaxToolkit AutoCompleteExtender, but that doesn't allow me to pass any parameters other than the content of the text box. I have all the ajax working to the point where I get a string array of all the autocomplete suggestions.

My question is, what HTML element should I use for the actual extender part? I know the prefab AutoCompleteExtender uses a <'ul'> element that it fills with <'li'> items, but that seems like it would be cumbersome to do with js/jquery. Is there a control that would allow me to bind my string array to it? What does Google use for theirs?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not use the combobox / autocomplete widgets?

Comment: Is that a package or something that is already available in jQuery? I only recently started working with jQuery (finally got vsdoc to work, thank god.) so I'm still pretty unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Yep, look at the jQuery UI library. AutoComplete is built in. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Thanks! Finding all sorts of tools today...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also pass a `ContextKey` to the ajax callback.

Comment: Is there a way that I can set the ContextKey to the value of a DropDownList selection?

Comment: you can do that using javascript. This article: http://forums.asp.net/t/1119865.aspx will probably be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`<ul><li>` is the correct pattern for this type of function.